# Port forward port 25 on a Firehol instance

Tags: iptables, dnat

I am trying to port forward through a Firehol box to my email server on port 25:

```
clienta:25 > firehol > email:25
```

This is a non-transparent connection. The command I am trying is:

```
nat4 to-destination [email-ip]:25 dport 25
```

For simplicity for now, I am going in and out of the same NIC. My routing policy is:

```
route all accept
```

I can't for the life of me get this working, and I've spent a ton of time searching for answers. I'm at the so-new-point of dealing with Firehol that all my questions are stupid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `For simplicity for now, I am going in and out of the same NIC` - That does not make things simpler, actually it makes somethings like NAT more complex.  Not even sure the rules firehol will generate would work in this type of setup.

Comment: Right. Trying to use a single NIC makes it somewhere between complicated and impossible. You need two (or more) NICs, or at least proper VLANs set up.

Comment: Oh haha okay I understand.

Comment: Either way, I ended up turning on masquerade and that fixed it. Odd.